# Eclipse for C++ Windows 7 64-bit PC

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc

I am using **64-bit Windows 7 PC** and **I want to develop C/C++ programs using Eclipse IDE**.

I have **tried DOSBox** but it was **not working** for me. Also, **I din't liked it** as well.

I just want to use Eclipse for the same. I tried using **CDT Plugin in Eclipse** but that doesn't worked.

When I create a new C++ project, there are different Tool Chains available - **Cross GCC, Microsoft Visual C++, MinGW GCC**. I really don't know what exactly it is. I tried all but I am getting error and snapshot attached :-

Basically, it is not able to detect what iostream, stdio, cout is.

[image]

**I tried different solutions available on other posts but none worked for me.**

I don't know what to do with it. I know I am having problem due to 64-bit Windows but I want to fix this now. Please help!

Comment: Did you install MinGW or Visual Studio? You'll need those as those include the compiler and the standard libraries, which should explain why it's giving you those errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MinGW, and then select the MinGW toolchain when selecting a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried different tool chains on Eclipse IDE, but nothing worked.
Then I installed CodeBlocks IDE and plugins for the same as well.

Sic: Now, I am running C/C++ codes on Code Blocks perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) and install the C++ compiler, don't forget to add the MinGW bin to the system variables under "path".

I recommend you using Visual Studio Code. If you do install Visual Studio Code, make sure to install Code Runner plugin to make running C++ projects easier.